# JOIN failure as result of "NULL" values that can't be detected

Tags: sql, join, hadoop, hive

I have a table in a hive database that holds financial data.

The table has 3 essential fields: symbol, date, and price.

To filter the table (mostly for learning's sake) down to the most recent stock price, I created a view, recent_prices, that provides the symbol and the most recent date.

I then attempted to join the full table and recent_prices using the following:

```
SELECT financials.symbol, financials.price, financials.date FROM financials
JOIN recent_prices
ON financials.date = recent_prices.date
AND financials.symbol = recent_prices.symbol;
```

When I ran this in the Hive shell, it threw an exception and failed with the message:

"FAILED: NullPointerException null"

I then tried to find which records may have been giving me trouble and so I issued:`SELECT * FROM financials WHERE symbol IS NULL OR price IS NULL OR date IS NULL;`
As well as:  `SELECT * FROM recent_prices WHERE symbol IS NULL OR date IS NULL`

Neither or these queries returned any results.

I then created a view from the financials table with:

```
CREATE VIEW temp AS
SELECT * FROM financials WHERE
symbol IS NOT NULL AND 
date IS NOT NULL;
```

After that, I tried joining temp with the recent_prices and it was successful.

How could this happen if the query for null join fields returned nothing?

Comment: I don't think the error message is referring to `NULL`s in SQL data. It sounds like an application error of some sort.

Comment: What version of Hive you are using ? Also can you tell if any of the table is empty ?

Comment: Using Hive 0.10.0 as part of CDH4; and I'm not sure what you mean by telling if any of the table is empty